# Laravel 9 photo albums upload image to database does not work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, apache2, laravel-blade

I am working on a photoalbums program. When I try to upload an image to the database nothing happens. There is no image in storage or in the database.

I have tried:
`php artisan route:clear`,
`php artisan cache:clear`,
and I did `php artisan migrate`

I did a `dd($request);` in the store method on the controller but that didn't show anything, the page just refreshes.

**Controller**

```
class FlalbumsController extends Controller
{
  public function index(){
    $albums = Flalbum::with('photos')->orderby('name','asc')->paginate(12);
    return view('albums/flalbums.index')->with('albums', $albums);
  }

  public function create(){
    return view('albums/flalbums.create');
  }

  public function store(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'        => 'required',
        'cover_image' => 'required|dimensions:max_width=140,max_height=210',
    ]);

    $filenamewithExt = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename        = pathinfo($filenamewithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension       = $request->file('cover_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $filetostore     = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
    $path            = $request->file('cover_image')->storeAs('public/flalbums/album_covers', $filetostore);

    //Create album
    $album              = new Flalbum;
    $album->name        = $request->input('name');
    $album->cover_image = $filetostore;

    $album->save();

    return redirect('/albums/flalbums');
  }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flalbum extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = array('name','cover_image');

  public function photos(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\FlPhoto');
  }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/', [HomesController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/albums/flalbums', [FlalbumsController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/albums/flabums/create', [FlalbumsController::class,'create']);
Route::get('/albums/flalbums/{id}', [FlalbumsController::class,'show']);
Route::post('/albums/flabums/store', [FlalbumsController::class,'store'])->name('store');
```

**create.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <form  action="{{route('store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name='name' value="{{old('name')}}"   @error('name')@enderror>
        @error('name')
        <class="text-red text-sm">
    {{$message}}
    @enderror
</div>
<br>
    <div class="form-group pt-20">
      <label for="cover_image">Upload</label>
      <input type="file" class="form-control" name="cover_image" id='cover_image' required>
      <br>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

This above is a modal. There are no error messages in `laravel.log` or apache2 error log
What am I missing?
Thank you for your help.